# String to number is wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a string to number in Javascript, but here is my problem :

```
var string = "068999999501111443";
parseInt(string); // 68999999501111440
Number(string); // 68999999501111440
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Because the number is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: @limelights - no, it isn't that. If it was, then the output would be a lot more different to the input.

Comment: You are over the integer max length of +/- 9007199254740991, so javascript will have problems handling this number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of finite precision numerical representations. Every such scheme will have numbers that it cannot represent exactly, just as decimal numbers with a finite number of digits cannot exactly represent one third. If you try to represent a number that cannot be represented exactly, it will be represented approximately. If you don't want this, don't use finite precision representations. For example, why not keep the number in a string?

Comment: @fuyushimoya : is there a way to handle large numbers in JS ? (i really need to use large numbers in my calculations)

Comment: Try google `big number api javascript`, should be some libs exist like [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/), [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/), or you can implement one. There should be plenty of resource to implement that.

Comment: @David Schwartz : i can't use string, i need numbers because i have to modulo this number...

Comment: @donpachi You can modulo a string. Do it the same way you would do it on paper. Surely you learned long division in school.

Comment: @David Schwartz : you're a genious ! i use your method and it works like a charm :) Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the number is too large to be stored accurately. It is being stored as a floating point number, which can only store a certain amount of precision. Beyond it's maximum precision, you'll get what look like weird rounding errors.

You'll get similar effects for decimals with a large number of decimal places. This is more well known, as it tends to occur more often, but it's exactly the same effect that is happening here.